# What is this "Setup" option in my iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud, bug, setup

It looks like some sort of bug. This icon disapears after turning off "iCloud Drive" couple positions above this. After turning "iCloud Drive" on and some time later this icon reapears.
I tried restarting my iPhone. I also tried "Erase all content and settings" without backup and starting from the sctratch.
When I was reintalling my apps I tried to establish WHEN this icon appears in iCloud, maybe with specific app or something but no luck...
I this some kind of virus? Should I be worrying about safety of my data and for exaple paying with my phone? Maybe this is some kind of spying virus??
Should I be looking for help from Apple support?

[image]